# Change the index of cell in row in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have following table:

```
<table class="AMDetailTableCss" id="tblQueueHistory" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" >
    <tr>
        <td id="Working">
            <div class="AMQueueName AMWorkingAgent"><div>
            <span class="AMQueueText">Working</span>
            </div></div>
        </td>
        <td id="OnBreak">
            <div class="AMQueueName AMOnBreakAgent"><div>
            <span class="AMQueueText">On Break</span>
            </div></div>
        </td>
        <td id="Idle">
            <div class="AMQueueName AMIdleAgent"><div>
            <span class="AMQueueText">Idle</span>
            </div></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to change the index of `td` at runtime using javascript/Jquery. I mean the second `td` should be moved to be the first.

How can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#OnBreak").detach().insertBefore("#Working")
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZT8PH/2/)

Using `detach()` will ensure that any events or data assigned to the `td` are moved too.

Comment: Are you sure `detach()` is needed? Not using it preserves some click events for example, so my guess is that jQuery takes care of this.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine You could be right actually. I assumed detach would be needed to remove the initial element from the DOM, although it appears that it isn't strictly necessary.

Comment: Yep, methods such as `insertBefore`, `prepend` etc don't copy, they move the elements. Also, seeing as jQuery keeps everything in `data()`, It's safe to think you don't need `detach()` if `click()` works without it.

Comment: You're welcome! This also means that if you *do* want to copy, you can't use these methods right away. You need to `clone()` and move the cloned element.

Answer (score 1):

```
var firstHtml=$('#Working').html();
var secondHtml=$('#OnBreak').html();

$('#OnBreak').html(firstHtml);
$('#Working').html(secondHtml);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ankur20us/eZZy9/)

Comment: This would work, but you would just be changing the inside of the `td`'s, so any handler tied to `#Working` would still be tied to the first `td`.

Answer (score 0):

When do you want to do this?

```
$("#OnBreak").prependTo($("#OnBreak").parent());
```